# NestedScrollView/ ScrollView is not scrolling when some layout are included to the child of ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

```
androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
LinearLayout
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
TextView
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
TextView
include
include
include
```

above is the structure of my XML, when I am including the layouts, the scrollview is not working.

Initially the included layouts are Visibility GONE and they are made visible when the checkbox is checked. 
the checboxes are not enough to make the screen scrollable but as soon as the included layouts are maded visible, the scrollView should scroll. But the layout cuts at the bottom and is not scrolling.

complete XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="annualRiskAssessmentVM"
        type="com.cmm_android.forms.risk_assessment.AnnualRiskAssessmentVM" />

    <variable
        name="fragment"
        type="com.cmm_android.forms.risk_assessment.AnnualRiskAssessmentFrag4" />

</data>


<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                style="@style/RegularBlack"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="My support will include assistance with :"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbMedication"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="Medication"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv2" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbPersonalCare"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Personal Care"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbMedication" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbNutrition"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Nutrition"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbPersonalCare" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbMoneyManagement"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Money Management"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbNutrition" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbShopping"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Shopping"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbMoneyManagement" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbSocialActivity"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Social activities or accessing the community"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbShopping" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbCompanionship"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Companionship (sitter service)"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbSocialActivity" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbWellbeing"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Wellbeing checks"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbCompanionship" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbDomestic"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Domestic"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbWellbeing" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbOther"
                style="@style/CheckBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:text="Other"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbDomestic" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                style="@style/SmallBlack"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:text="Now complete additional relevant sections below"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cbOther" />


            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_medication"
                layout="@layout/layout_medication"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv3" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_personal_care"
                layout="@layout/layout_personal_care"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_medication" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layout_nutrition"
                layout="@layout/layout_nutrition"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_personal_care" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have went through a number of posts on SO but no one is related to included layout's visibility.

Comment: why did you put ConstraintLayout inside LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is the dumbest mistake that took my whole day to figure out.

The first child of my constraint layout is constrained to bottom of tv1 which is not even present in the whole layout. (Copy pasting mistake)

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            style="@style/RegularBlack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:text="My support will include assistance with :"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv1" />
```

changed it to

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

and the scroll started working. :)